# SQL Server Spy in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012

I have a C# Winforms .NET 4.0 application with a SQL Server 2012 Database.  I has two database connections.  One to a security database and one to the application database.  Is there a open source .NET library or other that will allow you to capture and display all transactions sent over a given database connection in real-time.

The thought is while the application is open I would be able to display a dialog of all the on-going transactions (SQL Statements) being sent to the database.

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162182.aspx) on MSDN, but wondered if there was anything else out there.

Comment: Not a .NET library - but ***the*** tool to use for this is **SQL Server Profiler** on the SQL Server side

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using [Express Profiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/). While this is a *tool*, there is also the source code available, which should help you to built this functionality into your own tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions for how to do it using a SQL stored procedure: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx

Basically, you'll need to make use of (and, obviously get acquainted with the documention of) the stored procudures: sp_trace_create, sp_trace_setevent, sp_trace_setfilter, sp_trace_setstatus, and sp_trace_getdata. They're all obviously callable from C#.